# Unable to load the requested file: loadcountrystate.php in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Model:

```
function loadcountries() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT country FROM country_state");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}

function loadstatesfromcountries($country) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT state FROM country_state WHERE country = '{$country}'");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('countrystate','',TRUE);
}

function index() {
    $arrCountries = $this->countrystate->loadcountries();

    foreach ($arrCountries as $countries) {
        $arrcountries[$countries->country] = $countries->country;
    }

    $data['country'] = $arrcountries;

    $this->load->view('loadcountrystate',$data);
}

function ajax_call() {
    if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['country'])) {
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $arrStates = $this->countrystate->loadstatesfromcountries($country);

        foreach ($arrStates as $states) {
            $arrstates[$states->state] = $states->state;
        }

        print form_dropdown('state',$arrstates);
    } else {
        redirect('site');
    }
}
```

This is a drop down list. I'm frequently getting this error:

> Unable to load the requested file: loadcountrystate.php

Comment: have you created view file loadcountrystate.php

Comment: yes i have created

Comment: is the view file located in views, and not under a sub folder there?  Does it have the correct permissions to be read (on linux it's likely to need to be assigned to the web-server user or group, and readable to that user or group)

Comment: Do you have problem with `index()` method or `ajax_call()` method?